# How to call Http post and get request in angular 6

Tags: httprequest, observable, angular6

I am updating my application from MEANAngular4 to MEANAngular6 but still don't know how to do http post/get requests. Thats how I did it in Angular 4

```
  registerUser(user) {
  return this.http.post(this.domain + 'authentication/register', user).map(res => 
  res.json());
  }
```

Comment: [Reference](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";


  registerUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.domain + 'authentication/register', user).pipe(map(res => 
    res.json()));
  }
```

Comment: Please provide how the code above helped you resolve the issue.

Comment: I had made a service file, where other components like login, register etc are using the specific function in that file. Basically this is one function code of my service file, where i am getting response from my authentication.js file . Here the one variable is  domain = "http://localhost:8080/"; and for easy understanding 'authentication/register' means that go the authentication.js file and find the register API and fetch the response of register API.

Answer (score 0):

First you'd notice that you don't need map part because, when the response comes it will already be unwrapped for you.

And also return observable from the api wrapper function and using it will be as simple as I have shown you with the one line below the function.

```
registerUser(user: any) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http
    .post(this.domain + 'authentication/register', user);
}

let result = await registerUser(user).toPromise();
```